# configure nvim and oni to use bash on wsl in windows

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim

I tried to set `shell` variable in `init.vim` file, but it gives error
`E518: Unknown option: C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe`
but if try inside neovim like `:set shell = wsl.exe`, it works.

**init.vim**

```
    set shell = C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

without space works 
`set shell=C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`